# ggplot geom_errorbar width when faceting (and scale="free")

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a faceted plot using ggplot and geom_errorbar.  However, each different facet may have have vastly different x ranges, and so the width of the error bar isn't looking "good".  Here's a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame( group=rep(c(1,2,3),each=10), ymin=rnorm(30), ymax=rnorm(30))
test$x <- rnorm(30) * (1+(test$group==1)*20)
ggplot( test, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) ) +
  geom_errorbar(width=5) + facet_wrap( ~ group, scale="free_x" )
ggplot( test, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) ) +
  geom_errorbar(width=.2) + facet_wrap( ~ group, scale="free_x" )
```

In the first plot, the error bars for group 1 look great, but 2 and 3 are far too wide.  In the second plot, the error bars are way too small for group 1.  Is there an easy way to fix this?  I'm thinking I might just have to use width=0, but I'd like to avoid that.

[image: First Plot]

[image: Second Plot]

Comment: Is there a updated answer to this problem in newer package versions yet? @Didzis Elferts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Workaround for this problem would be to add to your data frame new column `wd` that contains width of the errorbars for each level.

```
test <- data.frame( group=rep(c(1,2,3),each=10), ymin=rnorm(30), ymax=rnorm(30))
test$x <- rnorm(30) * (1+(test$group==1)*20)
test$wd<-rep(c(10,0.5,0.5),each=10)
```

Then use this new column to set `width=` in `geom_errorbar()`. It should be set inside the `aes()` call.

```
ggplot( test, aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(width=wd)) + facet_wrap( ~ group, scale="free_x" )
```

[image]